# How to filter multiple restricted words in a string?

Tags: php, string, validation, filter

On my site I have a status update form which users fill to update their status with a maximum of 160 characters. So far on my form there are some restrictions like: *“A user cannot post >160 characters, if he adds >160 characters then a warning message is shown to him.”* It all is working for me.

> Now I want to add a restriction on the user input, meaning that if a user enters restricted words, then the post will not be submitted and the user will see an error message.

Restricted words: **Facebook**, **Twitter**, **Whatsapp**, **Mxit**, **Qeep**.
So far I am able to add only one word to my function, I want to add all the above words to it help please! thanks

```
 <?php

 $txt = $_POST['msg'];

 if (strlen($txt) > 160) {
     echo "Your post contains more then 160 chrecters";
     $checking = substr($txt, 160);
     echo "<del style='color:red;'>$checking</del>";
 }

 if (preg_match("/Facebook/", $txt)) {
     echo "the post contains words restricted!";
 }
 //else send data to the database
```

Comment: you are looking for word only ? i.e facebook or looking for abcfacebookxyz

Comment: @AnandPatel Facebook, twitter etc I have mentioned in my post, I dont want my users to include these targeted words in their post,thats it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the string is very short:

```
<?php

// Note that this will remove newlines!
$message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "msg", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);

// Note the usage of a mutli-byte function.
if (mb_strlen($message) > 160) {
    exit("Your message contains more then 160 characters.");
}

// Array containing the all lower-cased words which are restricted.
$restricted_words = array("facebook", "twitter");

// Lowercase the message for our search (again multi-byte).
$words = mb_strtolower($message);

// Create an array by splitting the words at the grammatically correct word
// delimiter character (a space).
$words = explode(" ", $words);

// Flip the array, so we can directly check with isset() for existence.
$words = array_flip($words);

// Now go through all restricted words and see if they are part of the message.
foreach ($restricted_words as $delta => $restricted_word) {
    if (isset($words[$restricted_word])) {
        exit("Your message contains a restricted word.");
    }
}
```

I see one problem with your whole approach, since you are only checking for perfectly typed words. Many projects in the past tried to impose profanity filters on their users and stuff like that. That's why you'll often see people posting `fu@#` or `dafuq` instead of the actual word `fuck` or `what the fuck`. Your users might simply resort to something similar and post `FB` instead of `Facebook`. Just rethink if such a word filter is really necessary. If it is, consider using the [Levenshtein distance](https://php.net/manual/function.levenshtein.php) to check if the words are similar (this will be an expensive operation and possibly yield false positives).

---

On a last note, the regular expression you were searching for:

```
<?php

preg_match("/(Facebook|Twitter)/i", $message, $matches);
```

The brackets create a group and the pipe is used to separate the various alternative words that we want to match. Last but not least the `i` modifier is used to make the whole thing case insensitive. The (optional) third parameter will contain the matches, so that you may tell the user which restricted words were found in the message.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$restricted_words = array("facebook", "twitter", "google plus"); //add restricted word or character in array
$replace = array(''); // add here word or character with whom you want to replace, i added blank because i want to replace with blank
$message = str_replace($restricted, $replace, $_POST['message']);
?>
```